# Calculating exact/approximate solution to a formula

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, dynamic-programming, approximation

Suppose we have a set of variable $\mathbf{y} = \left(y_1, ..., y_n \right)$. Also consider the set of functions $g_i(y_i), 1 \leq i \leq n$. Note that $g_i()$ is dependent only on $y_i$.

Consider the program: 
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C} \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(y_i)
$$
Where $C$ is the feasible space for $\mathbf{y}$. The question is how to find this equation(or an approximation to it) efficiently?

Note that naively computing this is $m^n$ (assuming that each $y_i$ can take $m$ possible values, although some of these combinations might not lie in the feasible space $\mathcal{C}$). To make it more clear consider the following example: 
$$
\begin{cases}
\sum_{(y_1, y_2) \in C} g_1(y_1) g_2(y_2)  \\
\mathcal{C}: y_1 + y_2 \leq 1 \\ 
y_1 \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace \\  
y_2 \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace  
\end{cases}
$$

You can make the following assumptions (but not limited to):

- $\mathcal{C}$ is be represented with a linear constraint: 
  $$
  A\mathbf{y} \leq b
   $$
- $g_i(y_i)$ is bounded above with some number $M$.
- g_i(y_i) is a convex/super-convex function
- Or any other necessary assumption that can help to solve or approximate this.

Update1: It might be useful to know that 
$$
\ln \sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C} \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(y_i) } { |C| } \leq  \frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C} \ln  \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(y_i) = \frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C}   \sum_{i=1}^n \ln  g_i(y_i)
$$

Comment: In update 1: Can you check the validity of your first inequality again? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it Jensen's inquality? You mean it should me like this? 
$$
\ln \sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C} \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(y_i)  } {  |C|} \leq \frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{\mathbf{y} \in C} \ln  \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(y_i) 
$$

Comment: Yes. The one in the above comment is correct. Please reflect the change in your question.

Comment: OK, tnx for letting me know.